# How is Int actually defined in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The *[Learn You A Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)* book by Miran Lipovača says in the chapter *[Making Our Own Types and Typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)* that the idea of Haskell's Int type could be represented like this:

```
data Int = -2147483648 | -2147483647 | ... | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 2147483647
```

Nevertheless, it says that it worked just as demonstrative purposes, but it doesn't say how Int is actually defined. Is Int defined especially by the compiler or can it be definable with plain Haskell code?

Comment: It's probably implementation-dependent, but it appears to simply be a signed 32-bit value.

Comment: In GHC, it is `data Int = I# Int#`, and `data Int#`. `Int#` is magic which is compiled in a special way, the compiler will treat it as an `int` in the resulting c code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Int.html#Int8

The above is the sized (and I believe signed) Int datatypes, but the default `Int` is a built-in.

He's making a point about how algebraic datatypes encode "precise" types that outline what the members of the type are. This is in some respects a step removed from dependent typing but that's another kettle of fish.

Answer (score 6):

`Int` is magic - defined by the compiler. As the other authors have said, it is not actually defined as an algebraic data type, it is implementation-defined, much like `Double`!

There are some rules though, `Int` is guaranteed to be at least a 30-bit signed integer. `Int` must be able to express every value in the range `[-2^29, 2^29)` (upper bound exclusive). In practice, `Int` is defined by the compiler to be equivalent to a 32-bit integer value. The reason for this is that `Int` can be optimized in certain ways that a machine word cannot. Pointer tagging is important for Haskell performance, and so implementations are free to use some number of bits.

If you want guaranteed sized values, `Data.Int` has `Int32`, and `Data.Word` has `Word32`, which guarantee exact correspondance to 32-bit signed and unsigned machine integers.

Comment: With GHC, `Int`s size depends on the platform word size.  On a 64-bit platform, ghc will use 64-bit `Int`s.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain about that - anyhow, it doesn't change the specification. `Int` is defined to be a signed integer with a range of at least `[-2^29, 2^29)`.

Comment: Yes, that's how `Int` is defined by the Haskell spec.  However, GHC guarantees larger Int sizes (at least currently, and I think it's unlikely to change) http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/bugs-and-infelicities.html#haskell-98-2010-undefined

Answer (score 3):

It could be defined in Haskell by actually defining all 2^32 constructors (which couldn't be called `1`, `2` etc. since those aren't legal constructor names) and then defining `fromInteger` appropriately. However that would not be very practical.

In all real-world implementations `Int` is a built-in.